# scraping a single html table in python using find

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am absolutely new to python and am trying to scrape a single table from a webpage.  I have accessed the html via "inspect" in Chrome.  The web page is here:

https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01.html

The following is the code I have used

```
import bs4
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#name a page to scrape
my_url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01.html'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#perform html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

There is a table on the page called "Salaries".  I would like to scrape this table, along with the Title of the page and eventually put them in a csv file.  However, I first need to get the salary table.  I have been trying to use the `find` function from `BeautifulSoup` since it's only one table that I am interested in. The problem is that I get no results when I run the following code:

```
page_soup.find("table", id = "all_salaries")
```

I am using Chrome and when I use the "inspect" tool on the table it looks like the id is "all_salaries" but I am getting no results.  Is there a reason why I am getting no results?  What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished via `csv` writer and the `find_all` function.

```
import bs4, csv
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#name a page to scrape
my_url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01.html'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#perform html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

with open('csvOut.csv','w') as myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile, lineterminator='\n')
    table = page_soup.find({"class" : "full_table"})
    for row in page_soup.find_all("tr"):
        rowTds = [td.text for td in row.find_all("td")]
        if len(rowTds):
            writer.writerow(rowTds)
```

Comment: is there a way to show the table?  Or at least send the csv file to a folder?

Comment: Open it in excel or notepad